# Error while copying an entire folder which has special character files to another folder python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to copy a folder which has many special characters files such as (misc_wall_stone_bumpäöüáß日本語їнськаייִדיש中neÄÖÜß.tif)
(testäöü ייִדיש日本語їнськаייִדיש中文ÄÖÜß.png)
to another folder. But it is failing with

```
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:'misc_wall_stone_bump\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb6\xc3\xbc\xc3\xa1\xc3\x9f????????????????ne\xc3\x84\xc3\x96\xc3\x9c\xc3\x9f.tif'
```

We are using python 2.7

program:

```
def rttCopyTree(src, dst, nolog=False):
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
    names = os.listdir(src)
    for name in names:
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        try:
            if os.path.isdir(srcname):
                rttCopyTree(srcname, dstname, True)
            else:
                shutil.copy(srcname, dstname)
        except (IOError, os.error) as why:
            rttFatal("failed to copy " + srcname + " to " + dstname + "Error: " + str(why))
    if not nolog:
        test.log("End of copying files.")
```

The program should copy all the files in source folder to destination folder

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the provided function?? It says `invalid mode ('rb')` which I can't see in the provided snippet.

Comment: The error comes from shutil.copy which executes the open(..) command

Comment: did this code copy any file to the destination folder? or it didn't copy any?